# How to find sensor specifications in Tizen Native (Gear S2)

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, samsung-galaxy-gear

Does any body know what are the specifications of accelerometer and gyroscope sensors in Gear S2. Or how to find using Tizen Native Application. 
The specification information required is vendor, noise and output rate of the sensors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the API functions provided in Tizen Sensor Native API to retrieve such Info.

Here's a Code sample:

```
#include <sensor.h>

static void
get_sensor_data()
{
sensor_h sensor_h;
sensor_get_default_sensor (SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER, &sensor_h);

/*
SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER        <Accelerometer (0)>
SENSOR_LINEAR_ACCELERATION  <Linear acceleration sensor (2)>
SENSOR_GYROSCOPE            <Gyroscope (6)>
*/

sensor_type_e type;
sensor_get_type(sensor_h, &type);
dlog_print(DLOG_DEBUG, "sensor-data", "Sensor type:%d",type);

char **name;
sensor_get_name (sensor_h, &name);
dlog_print(DLOG_DEBUG, "sensor-data", "Sensor Name:%s",name);

char **vendor;
sensor_get_name (sensor_h, &vendor);
dlog_print(DLOG_DEBUG, "sensor-data", "Vendor Name:%s",vendor);

float min_range;
sensor_get_min_range(sensor_h, &min_range);
dlog_print(DLOG_DEBUG, "sensor-data", "Min range:%f",min_range);

float max_range;
sensor_get_max_range(sensor_h, &max_range);
dlog_print(DLOG_DEBUG, "sensor-data", "Max range:%f",max_range);

float resolution;
sensor_get_resolution(sensor_h, &resolution);
dlog_print(DLOG_DEBUG, "sensor-data", "Resolution:%f",resolution);
}
```

Check out the [API References](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.3.2/org.tizen.native.wearable.apireference/group__CAPI__SYSTEM__SENSOR__MODULE.html) for detailed Documentations. As far as I've seen there's no function for noise.

[image]